# Strange Behavior of jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I use jQuery Validate and when I submit the form it shows just one required field and it shows others only when I click on them, and on the next one.

This is the script and the body:

```
 jQuery(function () {
        $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                Yritys: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                Henkilönimi: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                Asema_yrityksessa: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                Puhelin_Nr: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                e_Mail: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                Keskustelun_aihe: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                messages: {
                    Yritys: {
                        required: "You must enter something",
                        minlength: "You must enter more than 3 characters"
                    },
                    Henkilönimi: {
                        required: "You must enter something",
                        minlength: "You must enter more than 3 characters"
                    },
                    Asema_yrityksessa: {
                        required: "You must enter something",
                        minlength: "You must enter more than 3 characters"
                    },
                    Puhelin_Nr: {
                        required: "You must enter something",
                        minlength: "You must enter more than 3 characters"
                    },
                    e_Mail: {
                        required: "You must enter something",
                        minlength: "You must enter more than 3 characters"
                    },
                    Keskustelun_aihe: {
                        required: "You must enter something",
                        minlength: "You must enter more than 10 characters"
                    }
                }
            },

        });

    });


 <div class="divInfo">
        <form id="form1">
            <span>Yritys:</span><br />
            <input id="Yritys" type="text" required /><br />
            <span>Henkilönimi:</span><br />
            <input id="Henkilönimi" type="text" required /><br />
            <span>Asema yrityksessa:</span><br />
            <input id="Asema_yrityksessa" type="text" required /><br />
            <span>Puhelin Nr:</span><br />
            <input id="Puhelin_Nr" type="text" required /><br />
            <span>e-Mail:</span><br />
            <input id="e_Mail" type="text" required /><br />
            <span>Keskustelun aihe:</span><br />
            <textarea id="Keskustelun_aihe" maxlength="140" style="width:300px;height:150px;" required>Enter Text Here...</textarea><br />
            <span style="color:red; margin-left:0;">Keskustelun aihe max 140 merkkia</span>
            <div id="textarea_feedback" style="opacity:0.5"></div>
            <div class="butt"><pre style="font-size:x-large">Vahvista varaus klikkamalla tässä>>>>>>>>>>>>><button id="submit" type="submit" name="appointment" value="" class="btn-warning" /></pre></div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

Why does this happen?  It works, but it's not working properly. I can't find the solution.

**EDIT:**

THIS HAPPENS:

[image]

Comment: *"wtf is going on"* ~ Please do not use expletives, acronyms, text-speak, or anything but proper English grammar on SO.  Edited.  Thank you.

Comment: sorry, I got caught up in the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this happen? It works, but it's not working properly ...

You **MUST** have a `name` attribute on every input considered for validation, and the `name` is the only thing that can be referenced from the `rules` object of `.validate()`.

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        Yritys: {      // <- this must be the NAME
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        Henkilönimi: { // <- this must be the NAME
            ....
```

> ... I can't find the solution

[**Official Documentation: Markup recommendations** -](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations)

> ***Mandated***: A 'name' attribute is required for all input elements needing validation, and the plugin **will not work** without this.

---

You also accidentally put the `messages` object inside of `rules`, which are supposed to be siblings.

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        ....
    },
    messages: {
        ....
    }
});
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/2o9Lxkej](http://jsfiddle.net/2o9Lxkej)

Comment: @MicroDev, you also accidentally put `messages` inside of `rules`.  Fix this and it works:  http://jsfiddle.net/2o9Lxkej/

Comment: I guess it should work, but it doesn't in my visual studio, i even copied the code from fiddle and it still isn't working. ill just go on without validate, but your answer is correct